# How does compression in hive results in better query performance?

Tags: hadoop, hive, compression, gzip

Many best practices suggest that the data should be stored in a compressed format in HDFS.

There are clear performance differences while running a hive queries on a table comprising of compressed text files ( chunked gzip files of around 250 MB each) vs uncompressed textfile.

Can somebody please explain what is happening behind the scenes?

As per my understanding, while the query input is being assigned to mapper tasks, there is a decompression stage and then there is a query. If this is the case, how can it provide better performance over uncompressed text file as it will have the overhead of decompression?

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects involved here:

1. Network overhead: Map Reduce paradigm is heavily criticized for overhead for shuffle and sorting. If you look the processing steps in very selfish way then these steps are not contributing anything in the processing you want. Plus when bigger data flows thru the network in physical level even if you employ gigabit freq switch then also (if its not about very involved operation) then shuffle-sort becomes bottleneck. Hence more compressed the data easily it can pass thru the shuffle sort bottleneck.
2. Sparse Data: Bigger dataset are mostly sparse (Exceptions exist but take it as rule of thumb). So compression brings down the size of the data and then again shuffle sort step is pretty small.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, it does explain some of the things. We have a SAN storage attached to the cluster. So does the performance bottleneck still come into play?

Comment: I am not 100% knowledgable of SAN but if SAN can not improve in massive data flow in between multiple mappers and multiple reducers then it will become bottleneck.

Answer (score -1):

data compressesion in Hive tables has is been known to give better performance than uncompressed storage, both in terms of disk usage and query performance.

You can import text files compressed with Gzip  directly into a table stored as TextFile. The compression will be detected automatically and the file will be decompressed on-the-fly during query execution.

Record compresses each value individually while BLOCK buffers up 1MB (default) before doing compression.